# stWSO2ESB OutSequence Processing

Tags: esb, bus, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I'm transforming XML request to SOAP via XSLT in WSO2ESB, just wondering is it possible to make request parameter available to be used in response?

E.g.

```
<request>
<test>123</test>
<param1>testing</param1>
</request>
```

-> converted to SOAP

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">#S:Body><ns2:testrequest xmlns:ns2="http://xml.testing.com/test"><teststring>testing</teststring></ns2:testrequest></S:Body></S:Envelope></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

In the response

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:testresponse xmlns:ns2="http://xml.testing.com/test"><responsestring>success</responsestring></ns2:testresponse></S:Body></S:Envelope></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to return in XML

```
<responsestring>
<test>123</test>
<return1>success</return1>
</responsestring>
```

As you see, 123 isn't send to the server and has not received from the server. However, client is sending this parameter and i would like to just use this parameter in request and send back in response, is this possible? By how? I'm very new to synapse and very new to WSO2ESB, could anyone please enlighten me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can use [property mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB450/Property+Mediator) in the Insequence to set the required value as a property and then add it in the outsequence to response using [enrich mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB450/Enrich+Mediator).

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now. 
Simply by adding the property mediator in both insequence and outsequence together with the XSLT, where the xslt is trying to get the value from test property. That's it!

Insequence

```
 <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="TEST" expression="//request/*[local-name()=test]" scope="default"/>
```

outsequence

```
<xslt key="xxxx.xslt">
<property name="test" expression="get-property('TEST')"/>
</xslt>
```