# Pass property from inSequence to outSequence

Tags: wso2, hl7, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I'm sending a message with a Proxy to a HL7 TCP/IP port and get the response in the outSequence. But my problem is that all properties set in the inSequence are not anymore available. All of them are null. I tested with all the different scopes (transport, axis2, axis2-client), but none of them worked.

[I saw in this post that it should be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144596/stwso2esb-outsequence-processing). Is the HL7 sender destroying the properties?
**How can use my properties from the inSequence in the outSequence?**

Example of my Proxy (get message from ActiveMQ JMS and sends to HL7 port 4000):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" xmlns:hl7="http://wso2.org/hl7"  xmlns:urn="urn:hl7-org:v2xml" name="demo_toHL7" transports="jms" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">demo_qFilter</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">queueBlocking</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.DestinationType">queue</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
        <rules>
            <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
            <default>application/edi-hl7</default>
        </rules>
    </parameter>
    <target faultSequence="rollbackSequence">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
            <property name="ClientApiNonBlocking" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
            <property name="testProperty" value="blabla" scope="transport"/>
            <property name="messageType" value="application/edi-hl7" scope="axis2"/>
            <property name="ContentType" value="application/edi-hl7" scope="axis2"/>            
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="hl7://localhost:4000"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="PROPERTY" expression="get-property('transport','testProperty')"/>
            </log>
        </outSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

---

I'm using WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 and installed the HL7 Feature. As receiver I use the 7edit application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with property scope as "default/synapse"

FiveO edit comment:

Try with property scope as "default":

Sending a transport property from the inSequence to the outSequence (on behalf of the default scope):

```
<inSequence>
   ...
   <property name="myPropertyInTransport" value="myValue" scope="transport"/>
   <property name="myPropertyInDefault" expression="get-property('transport','myPropertyInTransport')" scope="default"/>
   ...
</inSequence>
<outSequence>
   ...
   <property name="myPropertyInTransport" expression="get-property('default', 'myPropertyInDefault')" scope="transport"/>
   <!-- Now myProperty is also available in the outSequence -->
   ...
</outSequence>
```

Comment: no - I get this error: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Only 'axis2' or 'transport' or 'axis2-client' values are allowed for attribute scope for a property med
iator, Unsupported scope default/synapse

Comment: How did you defined the scope? <property name="prop" expression="get-property('testProperty')" scope="default"/>

Comment: Thanks I was able to achieve the result by sending the properties within the "default" scope to the outSequence. I'll modify your answer with some examples.

Comment: Thanks..i added your comment in the answer

Comment: @Ratha I need to send string value as response using class mediator.Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132859/how-to-send-response-as-string-using-class-mediator-in-wso2-esb. Do you have any idea about this thank you